# required Attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option having required Attribute. But I am using `type='button'` to submit the form. So it is not working for me.

Any one have any Idea How to solve this.
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What browser you test on?

Comment: change the button type="submit" to submit the form

Comment: I test in firefox, I cant do type='submit' bcoz i have to submit the form if button is clicked

Comment: Post your form code Here

Comment: `<input type="button" name="sub" value="Insert"onclick="window.location='insert_revenue.php'" />`

Answer (score 0):

change the button type="submit" to submit the form

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: I cant do `type='submit'` bcoz i have to submit the form if button is clicked

Comment: that's what is a submut button is for. If you have some custom handling to do, use the on-submit event on the form tag. Note that you can return false in order to have the form not submitted. Either you're sending data yourself or the form can't be submitted because it contains error.

Comment: I have to click in button to submit form. Bcoz i want to prevent form submitting when enter key is pressed

Comment: on-submit event takes effect after form is submitted.... but I need to stop submit form by pressing enter key and execute required attribute of select menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<input type="button"  onchange="this.form.submit()" name="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to place the button outside the form (and use a button tag instead of input):

```
<form>...</form>
<button type="button" name="sub" onclick="window.location='insert_revenue.php'">Insert</button>
```

But if that answer is not sufficient you can block the enter key:

```
<form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
```